# Assigning variables from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to send a username and password ,  which are from my database through an email to the users. How do i achieve the purpose? I am using the current code below and whenever i receive the email , i realised that the places for $username and $password are empty , which means the database values are not being sent.

```
<?php

$to = $email;
$subject = "Registered details with BFS ! ";
$message = "Dear $username, as requested , here are your login details. ";
$message .= " Username = $username  Password = $password";
$headers = 'From:noreply@bfs.com';
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Edit ****

full code

```
     <?php 
error_reporting(0);


$email=$_POST['email'];


echo $result['price'];
if($_POST['submit']=='Send')
{
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db('users');
$query="select * from user where email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(error);
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
echo "User exists";

$username = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$username'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);

$to = $email;
$subject = "Registered details with BFS ! ";
$message = "Dear $result, as requested , here are your login details. ";
$message .= " Username = $username  Password = $password";
$headers = 'From:noreply@bfs.com';
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}


else
{
echo "No user exist with this email id";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: well, are you sure the database query is right? And the correct values are assigned to `$username` and `$password`?

Comment: @simpe Please read PHP docs on strings and variables.

Comment: @rlatief and $simpe , i have added the full code.

Comment: **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT IN YOUR DATABASE AND NEVER EVER SEND THEM OVER EMAIL**. This is a huge security mistake and you need to stop doing this *immediately*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$username = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$username'");
```

Into this:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
$res = $res['username'];
$username = mysql_query( "select * from user where username = '$res'" );
```

and this:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);
```

into this:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);
$username = $result['username'];
$password = $result['password'];
$result = $result['username'];
```

If it doesn't work I must've missed something :-) But if it does, use it to understand more about how the logic works, and after that read about [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) and use it instead. :-)

Comment: holy moly it worked ! thanks a alot dude and thanks to @simpe for suggesting too ! :)

Comment: i wish i could vote up but it requires 15 reputations :x

Comment: no problem :) Just remember what I mentioned above, after understanding the logic you should learn to use PDO. It's not something for "advanced users", it's the "correct way".